Datatables 2.0 - Set a table with custom layout using default controls
Before 2.0 I could display three of the default controllers -buttons, search, and page length using the dom option:
$('#data-table').DataTable({
    dom: "<'row'<'col'l><'col' B><'col'f>>t<'row'<'col'i><'col'p>",
        //...
});

This effectively rendered this dom (more or less):
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">{Page length control}</div>
  <div class="col">{Buttons}</div>
  <div class="col">{Search control}</div>
</div>
{ THE TABLE}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">{Info control}</div>
  <div class="col">{Paging buttons}</div>
</div>

Check https://jsfiddle.net/g2vbru6a/23/
However when trying to do a similar thing using the layout option I can't set three controls on the top (nor the bottom) of my table.
I've tried:
layout: {topStart: null, topEnd: null, top: ['info', 'buttons', 'search']},

and
layout: {topStart: ['info', 'buttons'], topEnd: 'search'},

And similar things, but it will just pile one on top of the other. If I could use bootstrap's row and col I'd display them the same way I did with the dom option. Can you point me how?

Updated answer (October 2024) - DataTables >= 2.1
DataTables now carries default CSS which allows for having equally spaced feature elements above the table when using the layout option without additional adjustments. From the Release Notes:

Prior to 2.1, the default CSS would have rendered each feature on
its own line. Now features in a layout full-width cell will be
spaced equally along the row. Start and End cells also benefit
from this change and allow multiple features to be shown on a single
row.

Hence, the desired output could be obtained similar as shown below.


$(document).ready(function(){
  new $('#data-table').DataTable({
    buttons: ['csv'],
    layout: {
      topStart: null, 
      topEnd: null, 
      top: ['pageLength', 'buttons', 'search']
    },
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/dt-2.1.0/b-3.0.2/b-colvis-3.0.2/b-html5-3.0.2/fh-4.0.1/sl-2.0.3/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.0/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="data-table" class="table table-striped w-100">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>1111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>1111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>1111</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



Original answer (July 2024) - DataTables 2.0
DataTables currently not natively supports to have more than two elements equally spaced, see also the DOM Structure. However, this is possible by using a layout option similar to yours where all elements are put into a single array, e.g. into top, and then use a CSS Flexbox in order to define the spaces. Below is an example where this is applied, we obtain three equal-width sections containing the three items side by side.


$(document).ready(function() {
  new $('#data-table').DataTable({
    buttons: ['csv'],
    layout: {
      topStart: null,
      topEnd: null,
      top: ['pageLength', 'buttons', 'search']
    },
  });
});
.col-md {
  display: flex;
}

.col-md>* {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.dt-info {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.dt-buttons.btn-group.flex-wrap {
  justify-content: center;
}

.dt-search {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/dt-2.0.8/b-3.0.2/b-colvis-3.0.2/b-html5-3.0.2/fh-4.0.1/sl-2.0.3/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.8/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="data-table" class="table table-striped w-100">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>1111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>1111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>1111</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



